# Caesar Cipher Query

Tags: python, python-3.5, caesar-cipher

Okay, so here it is, my code, the problem with it is that I can't seem to get it to return to its original form when I choose the Decrypt option, and I am not sure what is wrong with it. And I was wondering if you guys could give me some pointers as to what is wrong and as to what I should do?
Here is my code:

```
Choice = input("Would you like to decrypt or encrypt a message?\nPlease enter 'E' or 'D': ")
Message = input("Enter text to Cipher: ")
Offset = int(input("Please enter your offset: "))
Encrypt = ''
Decrypt = ''

if (Choice == 'e') or (Choice == 'E'):
    for character in Message:
        x = ord(character) - 32
        Encrypt += chr(((Offset + x) % 94) + 32)
    print(Encrypt)
if (Choice == 'd') or (Choice == 'D'):
    for character in Message:
        x = ord(character) - 32
        Decrypt += chr(((Offset - x) % 94) + 32)
    print(Decrypt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write:

```
    Decrypt += chr((( x -Offset) % 94) + 32)
```

not

```
    Decrypt += chr(((Offset - x) % 94) + 32)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line:

```
Decrypt += chr(((Offset - x) % 94) + 32)
```

I’m not sure where you got (Offset – x) from; you want to reverse the offset applied by the encryption process, so this line should be:

```
Decrypt += chr(((x - Offset) % 94) + 32)
```

You may want to adjust the Encrypt line to be symmetric.

---

A few other quick comments:

- You can tidy up the if branches like this:

  ```
  if choice.lower() == 'e':
  elif choice.lower() == 'd':
  ```

  You may want to consider the case where the user types something which other than E or D.
- The Python style guide is [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) – in general, variable names should be `snake_case`. The exceptions are classes (`CamelCase`) and constants (`UPPERCASE`).
- It’s not obvious why  you’re working mod 94, or adjusting by 32 places. It would be useful if your code contained a comment explaining this line.
- To reduce code repetition, you might want to wrap the offset code in a function. Then you could call it as follows:

  ```
  encrypted_message = offset(message, places= 3)
  decrypted_message = offset(message, places=-3)
  ```

  It would also give you the symmetry of encryption/decryption for free, by just flipping the sign of the offset.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch around the substraction, from

```
Decrypt += chr(((Offset - x) % 94) + 32)
```

to

```
Decrypt += chr(((x - Offset) % 94) + 32)
```

Also, instead of using the second `if` you should use an `elif` (which stands for "else if") statement.

```
elif (Choice == 'd') or (Choice == 'D'):
```

Just good practice.